# Finding an example series given the partial limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have been asked to find an example for a sequence with the partial limits= the interval $[0,1]$. The series I thought about was $1, 1/2, 2/2, 1/3, 2/3, 3/3...$
But I seem to have a problem writing a closed expression for this sequence.
Any ideas on how to approach it?

Comment: You actually mean “sequence” instead of “series”, right?!

Comment: Note that the numerators are $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4...$ and denominators are $1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4...$. Can you figure out closed forms for each?

Comment: Yes I'v translated it badly I guess

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the sequence $a_n=|\sin{(n)}|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed form for this sequence is
$$a_n=\frac{2n+2+m-m^2}{2m}$$
where the constant $m$ is the floor of the [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) index corresponding to $n$. For example the sequence of Triangular numbers; $n=0,1,3,6,\dots$ have indices $m=1,2,3,4,\dots$ respectively. Numbers - $n$ - that are between two triangular numbers have indices $m$ given by the previous Triangular number less than $n$. An explicit formula for $m$ is
$$m=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}2\right\rfloor$$
Hence a closed form formula for $a_n$ in terms of $n$ is
$$\large{a_n=\frac{2n+2+\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}2\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}2\right\rfloor^2}{2\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}2\right\rfloor}}$$
for $n=0,1,2\dots$